# How to output TimeStamp and ThreadID attributes with custom boost::log formatter?

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log, boost-logging

I'm using custom [boost::log](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/log/doc/html/index.html) formatter for color coding the output log message, but I'm failing to find the proper way to add *TimeStamp* and *ThreadID* attributes to the log. When I'm using file logging I just write `keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%] [%ThreadID%] [%Severity%]: %Message%"` as `logging::add_file_log` parameter. I want to have similar effect in the following custom formatter:

```
void coloring_formatter(const logging::record_view& record,
                        logging::formatting_ostream& stream)
{
  auto severity = record[logging::trivial::severity];
  assert(severity);

  stream << "\e[1m";

  switch (severity.get())
  {
  case logging::trivial::severity_level::trace:
    stream << "\e[97m";
    break;
  case logging::trivial::severity_level::debug:
    stream << "\e[34m";
    break;
  case logging::trivial::severity_level::info:
    stream << "\e[32m";
    break;
  case logging::trivial::severity_level::warning:
    stream << "\e[93m";
    break;
  case logging::trivial::severity_level::error:
    stream << "\e[91m";
    break;
  case logging::trivial::severity_level::fatal:
    stream << "\e[41m";
    break;
  }

  stream // << output TimeStamp
         // << output ThreadID
         << "[" << severity << "] "
         << record[logging::expressions::smessage]
         << "\e[0m";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that you have added these attributes to log records, there are multiple ways to extract them. The simplest way is to use [keywords](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/expressions.html#log.detailed.expressions.attr_keywords). First you declare keywords for the attributes:

```
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_timestamp, "TimeStamp", attrs::local_clock::value_type)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_thread_id, "ThreadID", attrs::current_thread_id::value_type)
```

Note that the third parameter is the value type of the corresponding attribute. In this example I assumed that the attributes you used were [`local_clock`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/attributes.html#log.detailed.attributes.clock) and [`current_thread_id`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/attributes.html#log.detailed.attributes.thread_id).

Now you can use these keywords to extract the value from log records.

```
stream << record[a_timestamp] << " "
       << record[a_thread_id]
       << " [" << severity << "] "
       << record[logging::expressions::smessage]
       << "\e[0m";
```

Comment: How could you apply `format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>` on that timestamp attribute?

Comment: Given that `format_date_time` is a formatter expression node, you'd have to construct a function object like `expressions::stream << format_date_time<...>(...)` (saving it in an `auto` variable or in a `basic_formatter` wrapper) and then invoke it with `record` and `stream` arguments. But that would be rather inefficient, you're better off with `strftime` or `snprintf`.

Comment: Spasiba Andrey, could you provide some examples on that? How may I record a custom timestamp? I tried with `boost::log::formatting_ostream os; const boost::log::formatter TSF(boost::log::expressions::stream << boost::log::expressions::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp","%H:%M:%S.%f")); os << TSF;` but it fails compiling

Comment: @PatrizioBertoni See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287547/how-to-use-boostlogexpressionsformat-date-time-in-a-custom-formatting-func).